# Multiple protection spells (Good and Law and Evil and Chaos) at once?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items

I am GMing my first Pathfinder game and a player (a wizard) wants to make robes that offer Protection from Good and Law and Evil and Chaos (as the spells). That seems a bit OP to me.

How would that work and what's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There isn't anything limiting all of these spells being on the same person at the same time, so that isn't necessarily a concern. Let's think about what the person actually gets by using an item like this. It would effectively be:
(all these bonuses are only against non-neutral neutral (many monsters fit neutral neutral, and definitely golems :D )

- +2 deflection to AC
- +2 resistance bonus on saves
- A second, attempt to save against mental effects at +2 bonus (+4 total)
- Prevents contact from summoned creatures of non neutral neutral alignment (spell resistance overcomes)

This probably isn't OP, as you can always just throw neutral monsters at it and it does no good at all.

#### Formula For the Item:

So, the formula for a continuous spell effect is spell level * caster level * 2,000 GP * 2 for 1 min/level spell, and each effect beyond the first has a 1.5 multiplier

- Protection against evil 1*1*2000*2 = 4,000 GP
- Protection against good = 1*1*2000*1.5*2 = 6,000 GP
- Protection against Law = 6,000 GP
- Protection against Chaos = 6,000 GP
- **Total Cost = 22,000 GP**

Honestly, if a player wanted to spend 22k Gold on an item like that, I would be more than willing to oblige them, as there are probably more broken things they could buy for that amount. Just my two cents.

As a point of reference, a [*cloak of resistance +2*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cloak-of-resistance) is 4,000 GP, and a [*ring of protection +2*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-protection) is 8,000 GP. Are the other effects (plus the fact that they're all on the same item) add up to another 5,000? Probably not. I would say that 22,000 is a minimum price, and just look north of there.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that this players has made a *robe of protection (but not from wolves, bears or rilmani)*

Answer (score 10):

## That custom magic *robe of alignment protection* wouldn't be particularly powerful

The deflection bonus to AC is [easily duplicated](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-protection), as is [the resistance bonus on saving throws](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cloak-of-resistance), and these bonuses won't stack as they're named bonuses. A second saving throw against mental control is only warranted against neutral creatures' effects, other creatures' mental control prevented completely by the *robes*. Summoned aligned outsiders that want to make bodily contact with the *robe* wearer will probably be rare unless the campaign's main baddies focus on summoning or something.

Thus if the campaign's focus is on magical possession or summoned creatures—you're playing a campaign based on *The Exorcist* or *Magic: The Gathering*, for instance—then such an item *is* a big deal and likely unbalanced, so the *robe* should be disallowed or outrageously priced.

However, in most campaigns paying 20,000 gp to 40,000 gp for a continuous [*protection from chaos*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/protection-from-chaos), [*evil*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/protection-from-evil), [*good*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/protection-from-good), and [*law*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/protection-from-law) is actually too high a price for too little of an effect.

Comment: Looking over the spell, it doesn't say that it completely negates any mind controlling effect from the alignment, just that you get a second save against any mind effect. I don't see alignment mentioned at all in that part of the spell effect.

Comment: @BaseHobo The spell [*protection from evil*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/protection-from-evil) says,  "While under the effects of this spell, the target is immune to any new attempts to possess or exercise mental control over the target. This spell does not expel a controlling life force (such as a ghost or spellcaster using *magic jar*), but it does prevent them from controlling the target. **This second effect only functions against spells and effects created by evil creatures or objects, subject to GM discretion.**" Emphasis mine.

Comment: I read that, but now that you put it on its own, I can see what you mean. So given this item under consideration, neutral creatures would be able to use mind effecting spells?

Comment: It doesn't actually say that it only blocks mental effects from the particular alignment.  Old versions of D&D did, but BaseHobo's quoted version implicitly blocks all attempts at mental control, regardless of the source's alignment.

Comment: @Perkins I think you have that flipped. The *D&D 3.5* version of [*protection from evil*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/protectionFromEvil.htm) says, "This second effect works regardless of alignment." The *Pathfinder* version of [*protection from evil*](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/protectionFromEvil.html#protection-from-evil) really does say, "This second effect only functions against spells and effects created by evil creatures or objects, subject to GM discretion." Or are you emphasizing that *GM discretion* part?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oops. Somehow my eyes blanked that line out. Guess I've been reading too much today.