# Do the magic item creation rules allow for feats to be added to items?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats, crafting

I have a player ([yeah, that guy](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/76706/multiple-protection-spells-good-and-law-and-evil-and-chaos-at-once)) who would like to craft an item that allows Weapon Focus (several actually) to an item they would like to craft.

Having read the Paizo website several times, I'm still not sure.

Do the rules allow for this? If so, how do I calculate the cost of these enchantments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### RAW: No.

Generally, you want to check out the [Crafting Magic Item rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items#TOC-Magic-Item-Creation) to determine what can be created.  The magic weapon crafting rules specify a bunch of things you can do (attack bonuses, special abilities, et cet.) but not feats. RAW this would be enough to say that PCs can't create magic items with feats.

### Example - A Flaming Weapon

Intuitively, this makes sense.  A magic weapon can burst into flames, giving it fire damage - this is a property of a weapon.  A feat (like Weapon Focus) is a property of the character - they are particularly talented with a certain kind of weapon.

### However - GM Shenanigans

There are a lot of magic items which look an awful lot like they give the user access to a feat. For example, the [Disarming Blade](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/specific-magic-weapons/disarming-blade) closely imitates the [Greater Disarm](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/greater-disarm-combat---final) feat. The Dueling property gives a bonus to disarm attempts (among other things), and the weapon's unique property is a weaker version of the feat's other benefits.

Although the rules don't specify how to create these items, a GM may always create their own magic items.  If you feel like this is a reasonable item for your character to have, by all means go ahead and create one for them. As far as the price goes, you will have to use your judgment. The Disarming Blade is slightly weaker than one feat, and costs +14,000 GP.

Personally, I would not allow a player to create such an item. They can already use enhancement bonuses to give additional attack/damage bonuses to their weapon; there is no need to shoehorn a feat into the weapon also.

Comment: On the one hand, weapon focus provides a +1 bonus to attack rolls, which isn't so far from what masterwork weapons already do. On the other hand, it's an untyped bonus, which means it stacks with the bonus from masterwork or magical weapons, which makes things complicated. Hmm...

Comment: Also, for 10k gold for an Opalescent White Pyramid Ioun Stone and 500 gold for a Wayfinder, you can get whatever Weapon Focus you want. Just don't have it stolen.

Comment: @IanJohnstone - That could be a good answer in its own right.

Comment: @indigochild - Good point. I will do that.

Answer (score 5):

For 10k gold for an Opalescent White Pyramid Ioun Stone and 500 gold for a Wayfinder, you can get whatever Weapon Focus you want. Just don't have it stolen.

The wording on temporary magic effects vs permanent magic effects is woefully unclear on most magic items. However, if you follow the process for stat increasing items, then the bonuses are permanent after 24 hours. This allows you to use this trick to qualify for other feats.

If you lose the prerequisites, you lose access to the feat. Weapon Focus is a prerequisite to many feats. If he uses this to buy a prerequisite, and gets out of hand, you can always have his Wayfinder stolen and have him quest to get it back without access to his subsequent feats.

If you are a particularly generous DM, you can extrapolate from the ioun stones that buying a feat without other feat prerequisites is about 5000 gold on a slotted item and 10000 gold on a slotless item.

This extrapolation is based on Scarlet and Green Cabochon Ioun Stone and Dark Blue Rhomboid Ioun Stone. Both 10000 gold and both give a feat without other feat prerequisites.

Answer (score 3):

**A number of existing items effectively grant feats**, and **you can make an item that does anything** if your GM allows it, but **Pathfinder provides no pricing guidelines for items that grant feats**, so they must be benchmarked based on exactly how useful the feat is.

According to the Pathfinder [rules on item creation](https://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html):

> Many factors must be considered when determining the price of new magic items. The easiest way to come up with a price is to compare the new item to an item that is already priced, using that price as a guide.

and:

> Not all items adhere to these formulas. First and foremost, these few formulas aren't enough to truly gauge the exact differences between items. The price of a magic item may be modified based on its actual worth. The formulas only provide a starting point.

Monte Cook, who designed the D&D 3.5 item creation rules that Pathfinder's item creation rules are based on, [takes the opinion](https://web.archive.org/web/20040808135128/http://www.montecook.com:80/arch_dmonly4.html) that **making items which grant feats is possible**, and there are several existing items which do just that, but he also says that feats vary considerably in power and must be priced based on exactly how useful they are:

> *How do you determine the cost and prereqs for making an item that includes a feat or featlike power (ring of evasion, weapon of mighty cleaving).*
>
> There is no standard for this. Not all feats or level abilities (like evasion) are equal. Use the existing items as guidelines.

He also notes that the caster does not need to have a feat in order to make an item of it, which you can see in the prerequisites of existing items, although it would be reasonable house rule:

> *Why is it that the standard items that include featlike powers do not require the creator to possess said feat? Why is it that items imbued with skill bonuses (cloak/boots of elvenkind, gauntlets of swimming and climbing) do not require that the creator have some ranks in the skill being enhanced?*
>
> Uh, I guess it's just a matter of personal preference. It seemed that forcing the creator to have the feat or skill usually screwed the player who wants to make the item for himself. This would be a fine, balanced house rule to add the feats and skills (probably at least 10 ranks of the skill) to the prerequisites for such items.

You must also consider that feats are often used as prerequisites for prestige classes and other feats. If they are available cheaply, low-level characters in particular may qualify more easily. However, an item granting a feat means that at least it won't *stack* with the feat, so at high levels a feat-granting item isn't all that powerful.

In your particular case, Weapon Focus grants a +1 untyped bonus on attacks with one sort of weapon. In pricing it, consider the following:

- It's certainly worth less than 30,000 gp, the price of the pale green prism ioun stone which grants +1 to all attacks, saves and checks, and which stacks with things like a magic weapon's enhancement bonus. That sets an upper limit.
- It's worth at least 5,000 gp, the price a dark blue rhomboid ioun stone would be if it weren't slotless. The item grants a feat, but it's a very weak feat, and Weapon Focus is clearly the more desirable feat.
- According to the combination of the [opalescent white pyramid ioun stone](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/h-l/ioun-stones/opalescent-white-pyramid-ioun-stone/) and [wayfinder](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/wayfinder-standard/) combination (with credit to [this earlier answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/76773/40971)), Weapon Focus is worth exactly **10,500 gp slotted**, with the limitation that you can only have one such item.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically yes, but the creator must have the feat in question, or have the assistance of someone who does.  For feats like weapon focus and weapon specialization, this would likely require the help of a fighter.  The GM could make you go on a side quest to find someone who has the feat you want, convince them to help you (at probably 10gp/hd/day).  And it would have to be specific.  A person with weapon focus in longsword, could not help create a warhammer with weapon focus (unless the weapon focus was in longsword, for a dual weapon fighter.)  Even still, I would also limit it to use only with the weapon it is on, though as a static priced bonus, you could add it to a weapon already at a total of +10.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. The future is *now* because questions can always use more answers. However, I'm concerned that there doesn't seem to be anything in the answer that *supports* the theory. Is there a rule that can be cited somewhere that says doing this allowed or acceptable using the guidelines that the answer provides? No matter what though, thank you for participating and have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with most of these posts and the pricing methods do help a lot for players and DMs who are trying to do this all, but keep in mind that a crafter doesn't need a feat to make an item according to RAW.  RAW states that for each requirement not met the Spellcraft DC to successfully create the item is increased by +5.  While it would surely help to have a fighter on hand to craft a Weapon Focus item, some more stringent DMs may even go so far as to say the Crafter must have the feat as this IS a grey area we are talking about.  For the Crafter to be required to have every feat and skill requested by his employer is far worse than any feat tax out there when the crafting rules state he can ignore a particular spell, or even be of insufficient caster level by adding the standard +5 per item or level missing.  As a note the DnD PC games that allow crafting work this way as well. I.E. Temple of Elemental Evil.
Side note for those readers playing Pathfinder, The books list the feat Master Craftsman, allowing anyone with the item creation feat to craft anything so long as they meet the spellcraft requirements for lacking spells and such, specifically allowing crafters of the wrong class, spell list, feats, or even alignments to craft so long as they have the (Admittedly much higher) Spellcraft checks.

As for making feat based Items there are clear, straightforward examples in any of the Metamagic rods.  Each are so specifically Feat based that that is the entire extent of their abilities.  Personally my advice would be to gauge the feat according to the usefulness (Or level increase for quick reference) of the metamagic feats.  There are enough Metamagic feats to support a wide variety of feat type power levels.

A Weapon Focus ring or Ioun stone seems a bit of a reach where a weapon with a corresponding feat would make sense.  I always liked where 3.5 DnD used slot based crafting (Movement on feet, Mental stuff on head, ranged and dex stuff on hands, etc). This sort of association guides the Crafter further on what is possible. If you notice though Scarlet and Green Cabochon uses two low level spells to make the Endurance Feat, and the Alertness stone requires nothing more than a level requirement.  Even among the Feat based items in the published books, true RAW, not always require having the associated feat to craft, but some associated spell or power. In any case the DM is always final arbitrator for his/ her game and Feat granting items should probably be kept to items that must be kept on hand to be effective and should probably have a direct association with the item if crafting non-printed items are even allowed in your game.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they do.  I looked at a list of items that grant feats and found two that allowed for adding feats that cost exactly 10,000 gp.  The first was an ioun stone that I could not find in the actual source material that granted Alertness (apparently in the *Dungeon Master's Guide*) and then the Fanged Ring in *Dragon Magic.*  The latter allowed two different feats: Improved Unarmed Strike and Improved Natural Attack - presumably only one would be used so they sort of overlap.

Therefore, it appears that you should be able to add feats for 10,000 gp - dissimilar feats for rising values - such as 15,000 more gp for the second - though I'm unsure if the third should be 20,000 or 22,500 (1.5^2 * number of feats).

I have not broken down a more complex item to make sure the rule holds - but it appears to be the rule.